# what's the meaning of "she takes a small measure of delight in the smudge of ..."?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Hadley takes a  small measure of delight in the smudge of lipstick on
> her collar, ...
> I know the meaning of [take delight in](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take-delight-in-take-a-delight-in) but I don't understand the meaning of the sentence.

Does it simply mean she was sorrowing over her collar got dirty by lipstick?

Here is the fuller text:

> Prada woman marches past with her cupcakes, her nose in the air, and
> Hadley takes a  small measure of delight in the smudge of lipstick on
> her collar, knowing lipstick, especially red lipstick, is very
> difficult to get out.

*[Hadley and Grace](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082WW397G)* by Suzanne Redfearn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"her nose in the air" means that Hadley saw her (the Prada woman) as arrogant. Hadley is pleased (takes a small measure of delight) that the perfect model (Prada woman) has an easily seen imperfection, the lipstick accidentally smeared on her collar.